# Should "best practice" and "best way" questions be considered primarily opinion-based or too broad?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

First, I **don't** think that these questions suit Craft CMS. Questions, recommending best way of solving problem or best practice of using something are:

- **primarily opinion-based**

  Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

or

- **too broad**

  There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Second, I noticed there is [best-practice](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practice) tag, which is certainly not good. This tag is off-topic and will encourage people to ask off-topic questions.

I expect that will be asked:

> But what about [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/10/250) question? It is highest voted question and off-topic?!

Not all top-voted questions are always on-topic. It is no doubt, interesting question, but off-topic. What I *would* suggest is historical lock.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

No.

A question with (measurable!) value to the Craft community belongs here. Your example is in a gray area, but definitely a question about Craft and not bowling, WordPress, or stamp collecting.

I appreciate that you've called this out because I think it's important to know what belongs so we can maintain an active and useful source of information. I don't have the answer, but I don't think valuable, relevant contributions should be excluded *on our site*.

When questions/answers seem too broad, it's our responsibility to encourage more brevity, specificity, and clarity.

If the best-practice tag repeatedly draws low-quality questions, we can address that if and when it's a problem.

Comment: I agree. We have had some very broad questions, but they've been dealt with very quickly. I do think it's good to allow (some) questions that encourage different opinions, you get to learn more and it adds more to the community. As long as the questions don't get out of hand (and they haven't yet) I think they're fine.

Comment: Good that you mentioned the point on how to deal with questions asked too broad. We definitely shouldn't discourage users (mostly newcomers) who ask unclear or unspecific (or use "best practice" in the title), but help them to get their question right, useful for others in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Yesterdays most interesting question (subjective, I know), asked and answered by Brandon Kelly:

[*"What’s the recommended way to set the site URL?"*](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/920/)

or put differently:

[*"What is considered **BEST PRACTICE** for setting the site URL?"*](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/920/)

Do you really want to close or lock questions like this because you read somewhere that questions "recommending best way of solving problem" should be considered off-topic?

I was very thankful that Brandon did this Q/A. It's valuable content like this, that gives me a reason to visit this site so regularly.

And I definitely don't mind if anyone uses the "evil b-word" to put a question. Yes, Brandon could have asked "How do you set the site URL?" to avoid best-practice implications, but what for?! SE is said to be very restrictive, but I think we as a community can determine where we want to go.

Comment: Ahhh ok, I see @nicael! The question is on-topic as it was answered by the creator of Craft CMS.

Comment: @nicael "best way" != "recommended way" == "proper way" == "right way"?

Comment: nicael, one wants to be kind here. In a ideal open minded community one might ask, 'what is _a_ way...to do sth.' That is what people really ask, and also want to compare answers. The need is that we are sensibly allowed to give answers. There are many examples on stackexchanges where excellent answers follow attempts at suppression as 'not right kind of question'. If the community of users decides a good question has been asked, they will answer. Moderation is only needed when there is no clear answer and noise, wouldn't you agree? Only opinion issues, vs. practical needs, easy for us to see.